# Get actual height of content in Silverlight Popup control

Tags: silverlight, popup, controls

I need to get the actual height of the displayed content inside an opened pop up control:

Problem:

I want to show a lot of data in a grid inside a pop up. If this content became higher than the browser height, this content is cropped at the end of the window.

I there any way to get the height of this content (i know that pop up isn't in the visual tree)?

Answer (score 1):

Try calling [UpdateLayout()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.updatelayout.aspx) once all controls have been added to your popup.

You will then be able to get the [ActualHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualheight.aspx) of the popup.

This has a bit of a performance overhead so trying calling it as little as possible.